# Can't access variables in related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a rails app with two models, visits and users. A visit has 2 users; a controller and an engineer. I've set up the relationships as follows, but for some reason I can't access the attributes of the related User. Is this because I am using devise?

*Visit Model*

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :engineer, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'engineer_id'
  belongs_to :controller, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'controller_id'
end
```

*User Model*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_many :engineer_visits, :class_name => "Visit", :foreign_key => "engineer_id"
  has_many :controller_visits, :class_name => "Visit", :foreign_key => "controller_id"
end
```

*Visits index view*

```
<% @visits.each do |visit| -%>
  <%= visit.visit_date.strftime("%a %d/%m/%Y") %>
  <%= visit.engineer.email %>
<% end -%>
```

This is where it fails, with the following exception:

```
NoMethodError in Visits#index
...
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

If I print the `<%= debug visit.engineer %>` there is an email attribute, but I can't actually get any of the individual attributes to display.

Any ideas on how I can access these variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that visit you are getting the error for, is a visit of a controller, not of an engineer.

try modifying your view like:

```
<% @visits.each do |visit| -%>
  <%= visit.visit_date.strftime("%a %d/%m/%Y") %>
  <%= visit.engineer.email unless visit.engineer.nil? %>
  <%= visit.controller.email unless visit.controller.nil? %>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: Thanks Tudor. It's always something stupid! I had forgotten to add the engineer and controller to the second visit in my list. Once I added these checks it was easy to see which one was missing. I added these through the console before adding the validation criteria. I'll accept the answer after the 5 mins.

Comment: I thought you said that if you printed out the `debug visit.engineer` and could see the attributes were set?

Also, for future reference, you can save some space if you use rails `try` method.  `visit.engineer.try(:email)` and `visit.controller.try(:email)`

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me as though your relationship isn't working properly.  Have you tried using the `:inverse_of` option for your associations?

Example:

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :engineer, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'engineer_id', :inverse_of => :engineer_visits
  belongs_to :controller, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'controller_id', :inverse_of => :controller_visits
end
```

Also, is there any chance you can name your association something other than `controller`?  Just a hunch but it may be a prohibited variable name in rails due to the fact that `controller` is a keyword in many of the classes.